# Short story; citizens allotted votes based on education, military service, etc

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to find a short story (1970's or earlier) with a society where people all get one vote at birth but can accumulate additional votes based on education, military service, and other positive citizenship accomplishments.

Answer (score 10):

This idea actually dates back to the **18**70's: it's present in [Mark Twain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Twain)'s short story “The Curious Republic of Gondour”. The [full text](http://www.gutenberg.org/dirs/3/1/9/3192/3192.txt) is available from [project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/3192).

> You must understand, the constitution gave every man a vote; therefore that vote was a vested right, and could not be taken away. But the constitution did not say that certain individuals might not be given two votes, or ten! (…)
>
> The new law was framed and passed. Under it every citizen, howsoever poor or ignorant, possessed one vote, so universal suffrage still reigned; but if a man possessed a good common-school education and no money, he had two votes; a high-school education gave him four; if he had property likewise, to the value of three thousand 'sacos,' he wielded one more vote; for every fifty thousand 'sacos' a man added to his property, he was entitled to another vote; a university education entitled a man to nine votes, even though he owned no property.

The general idea is known as [plural voting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural_voting) and has been applied in a few places in the real world.

Twain's story does not mention military service. That may come from a Heinlein story. Heinlein famously made the vote subject to military or civil service in [*Starship Troopers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers), and he explicitly refered to Twain's essay at some point, but the voting system in *Starship Troopers* is not a plural voting system.

Comment: I think the reference to Gondo[u]r is in *Expanded Universe*.

Comment: Strangely enough, because of the evolution of electoral rules in the UK a small number of individuals actually do get two legitimate votes in each general election - so, reality in fiction.